# Facing problem with suite level groups in testng xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I define groups at suite level, the testng XML file is not running whereas defining groups at test level is working fine.

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite thread-count="4" parallel="methods" name="Ahamed Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue" >
<parameter name="Environment" value="src/main/resources/stage/application.properties" />
<groups>
    <run>
        <include name="Smoke"/>
        <include name="Sanity"/>
        <include name="Regression"/>
    </run>
</groups>

<test name="Test1" thread-count="1" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass1" />
        <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass2" />
        <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass3" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test2" thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass4" />
        <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass5" />
        <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass6" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Am getting error like this:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 9; The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|suite-files)*)".
at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:327)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 9; The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|suite-files)*)".
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
... 3 more
```

Could someone please indicate what am doing wrong?

The line number 29, column number 6 denotes

> `</suite>`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to mention the groups above parameter tag. It worked. I don't know why. If anybody know, please mention it. I would make that as accepted answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite thread-count="4" parallel="methods" name="Ahamed Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue" >

<groups>
<run>
    <include name="Smoke"/>
    <include name="Sanity"/>
    <include name="Regression"/>
</run>
</groups>

<parameter name="Environment" value="src/main/resources/stage/application.properties" />

<test name="Test1" thread-count="1" parallel="methods">
<classes>
    <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass1" />
    <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass2" />
    <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass3" />
</classes>
</test>

<test name="Test2" thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
<classes>
    <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass4" />
    <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass5" />
    <class name="com.ahamed.test.regression.web.TestClass6" />
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```